# Why does Windows Store need the DNS client service to run (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, dns, windows-store

On my Windows 10 computer (and apparently others), the Windows Store app (or just "Store") will not start if the "DNS Client" is not running - Error "0x80072EE7".

Why?

The "DNS client" service is supposed to only supply DNS caching and name registration.

All other networked applications that I use on Windows 10 seem to work just fine without the DNS Client service, and I never experienced any problems disabling this service before - DNS is just resolved and cached by whatever DNS server/resolver that Windows is configured to use (via DHCP).

This issue is also mentioned at: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/app-store-isnt-loading-it-gives-error-0x80072ee7/2455d884-b66c-409b-a288-a5f1cf9aa025?page=2
But with no explanation.

I would like to know this because I generally recommend disabling the DNS Client service in order to make DNS troubleshooting easier (one less cache to worry about).

Comment: I don't see how knowing why makes a difference to you. Assume the answer is poor judgment on Microsoft developers part. What would you do about it anyway?

Comment: I can't help giving my opinion.  It's not polite to answer a question with "why are you asking that?".  Besides the obvious "I like to know for the sake of knowledge" you don't know why they wants to know.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat educated guess is that some of the content available from the windows store ( eg streaming DRM content) is not stored on Microsoft servers and to avoid assuming there is unfettered access to a dns server ( some, although rare, require credentials, in other countries dns lookups are limited due to content and location censorship ).

Rather than risk a lost sale, they embedded a dns client into windows. Its likely just a cache - gets updates when permitted by network conditions, but it could prevent some types of Windows store firewall blocking. Pure speculation here.

The best way to find out is run a traffic capture / analyzer program like wireshark or ethtool, use the store, and make adjustments to your normal dns service and see if can compensate or not even skip a beat. You could at least get a first order approximation of its capabilities fairly quickly.

Closed source OSes are fun!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I find your suggestion unlikely as the DNS client service has been in Windows since way back (it was not added to support Windows Store). And as for capturing network traffic - I just tried disabling our local DNS server (resolver), and enabling the DNS Client service. Windows Store still does not work. As soon as I restart the DNS server, Store works again. So it is clearly not the case that it somehow bypasses normal DNS.

Comment: Also, if this was indeed, as you say, "pure speculation" perhaps you should have posted it as a comment rather than a proposed answer?

Comment: The body of it is an assessment based on available info including some interesting dependencies. Without insider info from MS, connecting the dots has to be speculative. I simply acknowledged that. My answer to your question is that there is insufficient published information to allow a precise definition of the unpublished capabilities of this OS component; but if sufficiently motivated there are ways, which I covered, to further characterize it. An answer is rarely the finish line; a good answer can provide path forward. Its your call to decide if I provided that. The good news is its free.

Comment: To your technical comments - I think the service dependency is preventing a collection of that data - ie win store sees that that that dns service is not running, and will not run - period- vs. win store starts regardless, makes API calls against the dns client, which fail, and we can watch the failure mode. In order to get that data we'd need to decouple the dependency and trick the win store to start regardless. Behavior when not working is frequently more valuable in reverse engineering than the 'happy path', especially here where we start with (apparent) redundant capability.

Comment: And you've already further characterized it - that dns client is not used to wholesale replace std dns. If the dep. is not arbitrary, the client must augment the win store. I'm going to see if can remove that dependency between them on win 10 and I'll let you know. The existence of the dns client since win 3.1 (?) and the current inability to disable it without it breaking other things (new) was never disputed or ignored in my comments. In fact its the only solid ground to start investigating it from. it is a technical rabbit hole, if I'd asked the Q I'd want a fully realized answer as well.